# Zend_Form Failing validation with Optional File in IE10

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-upload, zend-form, internet-explorer-10

TL;DR: Zend_Form_Element_File is not playing nice with **IE10**

Alright, bear with me while I unravel this tale of one of the worst bugs I've ever encountered. (Only applies to **IE10**)

I'm using a Zend_Form (Zend Framework 1.12) with a Zend_Form_Element_File:

```
$file = (new Zend_Form_Element_File('file'))
    ->setRequired(false);
```

I'm also using [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) to use AJAX or an iFrame when appropriate.  (Which is a new development, previously I was only using an iframe [and this bug was found in that version] and I since moved the iframe to be XHR2 Feature Detected).

So we have this form that AJAXly submits the file and the other variables to the server, which tries to validate it through Zend_Form.  No big deal.  Chrome and Firefox send empty files which Zend detects and goes no problem, and IE was sending nothing related to the file, and is now sending an empty parameter named file (NOT an empty file) and Zend_Form is saying that the "file is too big."

The files array is empty, So I implemented the patch suggested on Zend Issue [ZF-12189](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-12189) to get:

```
    $check = $this->_getFiles($files, false, true);
    if (empty($check)) {
        if ($this->_options['ignoreNoFile']) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

but as `$check` is not evaluating as `empty` the problem persists.

Relevant Request Headers:

```
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7dd299161d06c6
Content-Length: 580
```

Request Body:

```
-----------------------------7dd299161d06c6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entryId"

9
-----------------------------7dd299161d06c6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csrf"

b9774f3998695465d9b3079eb028e342
-----------------------------7dd299161d06c6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"

test
-----------------------------7dd299161d06c6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"

2097152
-----------------------------7dd299161d06c6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"


-----------------------------7dd299161d06c6--
```

Form Messages:

```
{"file":{"fileUploadErrorIniSize":"File 'file' exceeds the defined ini size"}}
```

Does anyone know of a solution to this problem?

Comment: here is a workaround by hacking Zend_Form to fix the issue - http://stackoverflow.com/a/32472069/5207687

Comment: @Clay IIRC, I used a similar fix.  If you'd like to post that as an answer I'd be happy to accept it

Comment: posted it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a workaround you can add to override the Zend_Form's isValid() method.  There is a legitimate bug out there that generates the same error when no files are uploaded yet it still attempts to validate anyway.  Maybe this will help someone out there.

```
public function isValid($data) {
    $valid = parent::isValid($data);

    $errorCount = 0;
    foreach($this->getElements() as $elem) {

        if ($elem->hasErrors()) {
            $errorCount++;
        }

        // Related issues:
        // http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-12159
        // http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-10279
        // http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-12189 

        if ($elem instanceof Zend_Form_Element_File && !$elem->isRequired() && !isset($_FILES[$elem->getName()]) && $elem->hasErrors()) {
            $elem->clearErrorMessages();
            $elem->setTransferAdapter( 'Http' ); // reset any errors that may be on the transfer adapter
            $errorCount--;
        }
    }

    if ($this->_errorsForced) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($errorCount==0) {
        $this->_errorsExist = false;
    }

    return $errorCount==0;
}
```

Comment: Years on but still a valid answer for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to see this issue: [Form Bug in JS](https://github.com/malsup/form/issues/180)

When we ran into this, we just forced iFrame: true and that did the trick.  It made me a little sad, but it works. :)

Comment: I was already forcing iframe true and it wasn't working, I have since fixed the bug within Zend itself (similar patch to the issue but in the Zend_File_Upload_Adapter_Http)